# How to delete border in combox javafx

Tags: javafx, combobox

How to delete this borders in top, right and down sides;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find decision by myself.

```
.combo-box .scroll-bar:vertical {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
  -fx-border-color: transparent;
}

.combo-box .scroll-bar:vertical .track {
  visibility: hidden;
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
  -fx-border-color: transparent;
}
```